# Clarification of tf.name_scope in TensorFlow documentation

Tags: tensorflow

The [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/name_scope) mentions the following for `tf.name_scope`

```
This context manager validates that the given values are from the same
graph, makes that graph the default graph, and pushes a name scope in 
that graph.
```

What is the meaning of `given values are from the same graph, makes that graph the default graph` ?

`Same graph` refers to which graph ?

Also, what is the use of `values` parameter in `tf.name_scope` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply checks that `values` are Tensors built as part of the same `tf.Graph()` object. You can have more than one `tf.Graph()` in your program, and confusing things can happen if you mix nodes from two graphs. Most programs don't do this though, but often it is a good thing to check when writing library code.

There is no additional value to the `values` parameter than providing this error checking.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But the tensorflow documentation shows this example: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/name_scope#class_name_scope
which receives values a, b, c, which are not tensors (they are being converted to tensors). What does it mean to check for a non-tensor Python object to be "in the graph"?